# Pandas: Fill missing values using last available

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time-series

I have a dataframe as follows:

```
              A       B 
  zDate
01-JAN-17    100     200
02-JAN-17    111     203
03-JAN-17    NaN     202
04-JAN-17    109     205
05-JAN-17    101     211
06-JAN-17    105     NaN
07-JAN-17    104     NaN
```

What is the best way, to fill the missing values, using last available ones?

Following is the intended result:

```
              A       B 
  zDate
01-JAN-17    100     200
02-JAN-17    111     203
03-JAN-17    111     202
04-JAN-17    109     205
05-JAN-17    101     211
06-JAN-17    105     211
07-JAN-17    104     211
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `ffill` function, what is same as [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) with method `ffill`:

```
df = df.ffill()
print (df)
               A      B
zDate                  
01-JAN-17  100.0  200.0
02-JAN-17  111.0  203.0
03-JAN-17  111.0  202.0
04-JAN-17  109.0  205.0
05-JAN-17  101.0  211.0
06-JAN-17  105.0  211.0
07-JAN-17  104.0  211.0
```

Comment: Perfect answer. I'm just wondering can you achieve the same using apply function? For example this snippet will replace NaN with 'Is Null value'. I'm unable to come up with a logic to use the previous value instead. https://pastebin.com/raw/n384ba1q

Comment: @ChankeyPathak - I think apply is not necesary, simple use `df = df.fillna('Is Null value')`

Comment: No, I mean your answer fills the value using `ffill` method. Can `apply` do the same with additional logic? This is just for learning purpose. I'm just looking for an alternative to `fillna` for the OP's question.

Comment: @ChankeyPathak - Why dont post question? Sample data, your code, desired output? Because not sure how do you think use `apply`.